# Reducing requests and optimizing dynamic calls

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I am hosted at one.com, and have recently had the problem where users have been blocked from my site due to too many requests from the same IP address. I think that the reason is clumsy programming on my part (on calling the database). I have a dynamic call of several connections in a do-while loop, as shown:

```
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}


$unit_nr_var = $unit_nr_var1.'.';
$rs_nr = 1;
$te_unit_id_var = $unit_nr_var.$rs_nr;

mysql_select_db($database_db_stat, $db_stat);
$query_rs_theory = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tbl_exercise_theory WHERE tet_exercise_id = %s", GetSQLValueString($unit_nr_var1, "text"));
$rs_theory = mysql_query($query_rs_theory, $db_stat) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_theory = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_theory);
$totalRows_rs_theory = mysql_num_rows($rs_theory);

for($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {

$_cook_id = $_COOKIE['MM_cookieUserID'];

mysql_select_db($database_db_stat, $db_stat);
$query_rs_unit_[$i] = sprintf("SELECT te.*, tp.tp_answer FROM tbl_exercise te LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_progression tp ON (tp.tp_user_id = %s AND tp.tp_exe_id = te.te_id) WHERE te_unit_id = %s ORDER BY te_id ASC", GetSQLValueString($_cook_id, "text"),     GetSQLValueString($te_unit_id_var, "text"));
$rs_unit_[$i] = mysql_query($query_rs_unit_[$i], $db_stat) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_unit_[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_unit_[$i]);
$totalRows_rs_unit_[$i] = mysql_num_rows($rs_unit_[$i]);

mysql_select_db($database_db_stat, $db_stat);
$query_rs_name_[$i] = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tbl_exercise_name WHERE ten_exercise_id = %s", GetSQLValueString($te_unit_id_var, "text"));
$rs_name_[$i] = mysql_query($query_rs_name_[$i], $db_stat) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_name_[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_name_[$i]);
$totalRows_rs_name_[$i] = mysql_num_rows($rs_name_[$i]);

mysql_select_db($database_db_stat, $db_stat);
$query_Recordset[$i] = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tbl_exercise WHERE te_unit_id = %s ORDER BY     te_id ASC", GetSQLValueString($te_unit_id_var, "text"));
$Recordset[$i] = mysql_query($query_Recordset[$i], $db_stat) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset[$i]);
$totalRows_Recordset[$i] = mysql_num_rows($Recordset[$i]);

    $rs_nr = $rs_nr + 1;
    $te_unit_id_var = $unit_nr_var.$rs_nr;


if (($totalRows_Recordset[$i] <= 0))
{
    $i = 10;
}

}
```

I am aware that this might not be an efficient way to go about getting a variable number of tables, dependent on the page variable. The question then is: how do I go about optimizing this?

Comment: "due to to many requests form the same ip" sounds like something your hosting provider is doing, not your code.  Even if you code is slow as hell, users would still get responses, they'd just take forever or maybe time out.

Comment: Yes, my hosting provider is doing it, but I thought there might be something in my code that triggered it. That way I could optimize my code and work around it.

Comment: I kind of doubt that.  It's saying "too many request from the *same* ip", which probably means they're trying to protect against DDOS attacks.  You probably want to talk to their tech support about it.  Your code is kind of ugly, and you're putting *a lot* of work into preparing a string value (but kudos for not doing the obvious thing and exposing yourself to sql injection vulnerabilities).  Why not use an abstraction like PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)?  It does this work for you.

Comment: I'm trying to prepare about 5-8 arrays for each page, depending on a GET value. Also the rest of the code is kind of ugly as well :-)Anywho thanks for the link, I will try to read up on it and change accordingly.

Comment: I'm not asking you to do the work for me (that would take the fun out of it), but I could use a hint on where to start. I have never worked with PDO, and therefore out of my depth here.

Comment: I don't think that your code is the reason. Can you ask the tech support for more details? Like from which IP the requests are coming? To which port the requests are trying to connect to? What is the rate (req/sec) of the requests? Also what is the allowed parameters and what is the policy to get blocked & unblocked